# Product of two matrices equals zero

Tags: matrices, determinant

If the product of two $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ is zero ie: $AB = 0$

Then either $\det(A)$ or $\det(B)$ must be zero.

What additional conditions on $A$ and $B$ would be sufficient ?  Clearly the condition that either determinant has to be zero is not sufficient, as there could be some $A$ or $B$ whose determinant is zero but $AB \not= 0$

Answer (score 3):

$AB=0$ iff the columnspace of $B$ is contained in the nullspace of $A$ (or if you are instead viewing them as acting on row vectors, the rowspace of $A$ contained in the kernel of $B$).

The determinant of one of them being zero is just a very weak indication that at least one of them has a nonzero nullspace. Dimensions are not going to tell you very much: one needs to look at more detail at the interrelationships of these subspaces, rather than just their dimensions.

Comment: So one gets that the sum of the ranks of the two matrices must be at most $n$, but even that is far from *sufficient* to get $AB=0$.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but unfortunately I do not know what a kernel is. Is it possible to understand for someone with a basic level of knowledge in linear algebra?

Comment: @Quark The kernel is the nullspace.. I think I'll switch to that term instead. Also added a comment about dimensions being too coarse to formulate sufficient conditions.

Comment: I don't quite understand "...a very weak indication that at least one of them has a nonzero nullspace". Isn't determinant being 0 equivalent to nonzero nullspace?

Comment: @twosigma Yes, that is the weak indication.  It does not help you prove $AB=0$ at all.  You would need to add much more.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. I thought by "weak indication" you meant "just hints at the possibility", instead of "just tells you this little bit of information".

Comment: @twosigma yes, that’s right

Answer (score 1):

If we denote by $f$ and $g$ the canonical endomorphisms associated to the matrices $A$ and $B$ respectively then
$$AB=0\iff f\circ g=0\iff \mathrm{Im}(g)\subset \ker(f)$$